# How to send more attachments in one message/description? Discord.js

Tags: node.js, arrays, discord.js, message, attachment

I'm trying to attach all attachments from the report inside of one message, when someone will attach more files, the messages are sent separately with same text and different attachment, if someone will add 5 attachments to the report, I will receive 5 messages. I didn't find a proper solution.

This is what I found and tried so far, but it's not working..

```
      message.attachments.forEach(attachment => {
        const url = attachment.url;
        if(url) {
        const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ff0000')
        .setAuthor(lastMessage.author.username, message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .setTitle(`(Report)Bug report from ` + lastMessage.author.username + `#` + lastMessage.author.discriminator)
        .setURL('https://discord.com/channels/' + lastMessage.guildId + '/' + lastMessage.channelId + '/' + lastMessage.id)
        .setDescription(lastMessage.content.replace(/^([^ ]+ ){2}/, '' ) + ' ' + `[...]`, {
          files: message.attachments.array(),
      });
        client.channels.cache.get('ID').send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
        console.log(url);
        }
      })
```

`error: files: message.attachments.array(),`
`TypeError: message.attachments.array is not a function`

I'm using this at the moment, but this will send attachments in separated repeated messages.

```
      message.attachments.forEach(attachment => {
        const url = attachment.url;
        if(url) {
        const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ff0000')
        .setAuthor(lastMessage.author.username, message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .setTitle(`(Report)Bug report from ` + lastMessage.author.username + `#` + lastMessage.author.discriminator)
        .setURL('https://discord.com/channels/' + lastMessage.guildId + '/' + lastMessage.channelId + '/' + lastMessage.id)
        .setDescription(lastMessage.content.replace(/^([^ ]+ ){2}/, '' ) + ' ' + url); 
        client.channels.cache.get('ID').send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
        console.log(url);
        }
```

`console.log(url)` will log all attachment links, however I don't know how to use them in one message if someone will send for example 2 or more files...

Answer (score 0):

The `Collection#array()` method was removed in v13, you now can either use `Array.from()` or use the spread operator.

```js
Array
   .from(message.attachments)
   .forEach(...);

// Or

[...message.attachments]
   .forEach(...);
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but I kinda can't figure out how to use it properly to get result I want :-(

Comment: Also I have problem with it, because it says `Expression expected.` when I try to use `Array.from(message.attachments).forEach(...); `

Comment: `forEach(...)` is for the example. Replace `...` with your actual callback...

Comment: I tried something, but I wasn't successful. I'm not able to get attachments urls to the empty array, so I can use it...